# Get variables from child PHP class

Tags: php, parent-child

I am currently passing variabes to the parent controller_base using parent::

Ideally though I'd like to put a statement into the controller_base to grab these variables from the child. So that I don't have to repeat this statement in every controller that I make. How would I do this?

```
class controller_landing extends controller_base
{
    public function __construct($get,$post)
    {
        parent::__construct($get,$post);            
    }
}
```

Comment: If all you're doing in the child constructor is calling the parent constructor, then delete the child constructor

Comment: I'm not sure you can, as the parent could have many children

Comment: It's a bit complicated. I will have an abstract base controller that will be common to all controllers. Then there may be many many controllers such as controller_landing.

Comment: Are $get and $post variables actually $_GET and $_POST variables? if yes, you can just put them on your parent and delete the construct in your children.

Comment: Could you show us explicitly what you're trying to do in the parent that requires data from the child?

Comment: they are $_GET and $_POST variables. I just need to get them into the controller_base. However, I can only call the controller_landing directly because the base is an abstract class.

Comment: controller_landing inherits from controller_base, so delete the constructor from controller_landing and it will automatically use the constructor from controller_baes

Comment: Hmmm I tried deleting the constructor from controller_landing and everything stopped working :)